# How to access Vuejs methods to test with Jest?

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs

I have the following file: `deposit-form.js`.

With the following code:

```javascript
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        title: 'title',
        depositForm: {
            chosenMethod: 'online',
            payMethods: [
                { text: 'Already paid via Venmo', value: 'venmo' },
                { text: 'Pay online', value: 'online' },
                { text: 'In-person payment', value: 'person' }
            ],         
        },
    },
    methods: {
        submitDeposit: function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/deposit/',
                type:'post',
                data: $('#deposit-form').serialize(),
                success: function() {
                    $('#content').fadeOut('slow', function() {
                        // Animation complete.
                        $('#msg-success').addClass('d-block');
                    });
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    console.log(e.responseText);
                },
           });
        },
        showFileName: function(event) {
            var fileData =  event.target.files[0];
            var fileName = fileData.name;
            $('#file-name').text('selected file: ' + fileName);
        },
    },
});
```

I'm having problems on how to setup Jest, how to import the VueJs functions inside 'methods' to make the tests with Jest.

How should be my code on the `deposit-form.test.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is export Vue app instance.

```javascript
// deposit-form.js

import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.common';

export default new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {...},
    ...
});
```

Now you can use this code in your spec file. But now you need to have `#app` element before running tests. This can be done using the jest setup file. I will explain why it's needed. When you import your main file (deposit-form.js) into a test, an instance of Vue is created in your main file with `new`. Vue is trying to mount the application into `#app` element. But this element is not in your DOM. That is why you need to add this element just before running the tests.

In this file you also can import jQuery globally to use it in your tests without import separately.

```javascript
// jest-env.js

import $ from 'jquery';

global.$ = $;
global.jQuery = $;

const mainAppElement = document.createElement('div');
mainAppElement.id = 'app';
document.body.appendChild(mainAppElement);
```

Jest setup file must be specified in the jest configuration section in `package.json`.

```json
// package.json

{
    ...,
    "dependencies": {
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "vue": "^2.6.7"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.2.0",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.29",
        "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
        "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.5",
        "babel-preset-vue": "^2.0.2",
        "jest": "^24.1.0",
        "vue-jest": "^3.0.3",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.7",
        "webpack": "^4.29.5",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "./node_modules/.bin/jest --passWithNoTests",
        "dev": "webpack --mode development --module-bind js=babel-loader",
        "build": "webpack --mode production --module-bind js=babel-loader"
    },
    "jest": {
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "js",
            "json",
            "vue"
        ],
        "transform": {
            "^.+\\.js$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
            ".*\\.(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest"
        },
        "setupFiles": [
            "<rootDir>/jest-env.js"
        ]
    }
}
```

Also, you probably need to configure Babel to use the features of ES6 in your projects and tests. This is not necessary if you follow the commonjs-style in your code. Basic `.babelrc` file contains next code:

```json
// .babelrc

{
    "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "useBuiltIns": "entry",
            "targets": {
              "browsers": [
                "last 2 versions"
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "vue",
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
    ]
}
```

Now you can write your tests.

```javascript
// deposit-form.test.js

import App from './deposit-form';

describe('Vue test sample.', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        const mainElement = document.getElementById('app');

        if (mainElement) {
            mainElement.innerHTML = '';
        }
    });

    it('Should mount to DOM.', () => {
        // Next line is bad practice =)
        expect(App._isMounted).toBeTruthy();

        // You have access to your methods
        App.submitDeposit();
    });
});
```

My recommendation is to learn [Vue Test Utils Guides](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org) and start to divide your code into components. With the current approach, you lose all the power of components and the ability to test vue-applications.

---

I updated my answer a bit. As I understood from the comment to the answer, you connect the libraries on the page as separate files. Here is my mistake. I didn't ask if the build system is being used. Code in my examples is written in the ECMA-2015 standard. But, unfortunately, browsers do not fully support it. You need an transpiler that converts our files into a format that is understandable for browsers. It sounds hard. But it's not a problem. I updated the contents of the file `package.json` in response. Now it only remains to create an input file for the assembly and run the assembly itself.

The input file is simple.

```javascript
// index.js

import './deposit-form';
```

The build is started with the following commands from terminal.

```sh
# for development mode
$ yarn run dev
# or
$ npm run dev

# for production mode
$ yarn run build
# or
$ npm run build
```

The output file will be placed in the directory `./dist/`. Now instead of separate files you need to connect only one. It contains all the necessary for the library and your code.

I used webpack to build. More information about it can be found in the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts). Good example you can find in [this article](https://www.valentinog.com/blog/webpack-tutorial/).

Comment: Your answer was very useful and I could setup Jest and run the test !! but now when I run my deposit-form.html I'm having an error. 

Console points me the following error: 

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

on line:
1 import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.common.js

It doesn't recognize 'Vue'

Do you know why this might be happening ?

Comment: I apologize for the long answer. I updated the answer to the question. This should solve the problem.